# does ngModel create two way data binding if used without "banana" wrapping

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

[In this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven) Todd Motto explains that:

> ngModel = if no binding or value is assigned, ngModel will look for a
>   name attribute and assign that value as a new Object key to the global
>   ngForm Object:
>
> ```
> <form novalidate #f="ngForm">
>   ...
>     <input
>      type="text"
>      placeholder="Your full name"
>      ngModel>
>   ...
> </form>
> ```

And about "banana" wrapping:

> [(ngModel)] = two-way binding syntax, can set initial data from the
>   bound component class, but also update it:
>
> ```
> <form #f="ngForm">
>   ...
>     <input
>       type="text"
>       placeholder="Your full name"
>       name="name"
>       [(ngModel)]="user.name">
>   ...
> </form>
> ```

So I was expecting to see `[(ngModel)]` used in his final example. However, he used the plain `ngModel` directive. Does it create two-way data-binding? It seems that it doesn't create any binding at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates one way binding to `form.value[name]`, `ngModel` in this case just updates corresponding property in forms `value` object.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

Comment: thanks, so what's the difference between `ngModel` and `[ngModel]` if both create one-way binding?

Comment: The difference is in binding direction, [ngModel] will update <input> value using model value, ngModel will update model value (`form.value` in this case) using <input> value.