# Form values not initialized when new ng-container is loaded

Tags: angular, angular-forms

`Plunkr` link: https://plnkr.co/edit/MOQ1evhsAocw3cJrYM0q?p=preview

I have the following `ngSwitch` code in my HTML template:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="f.value.visitFrequency">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'weekday'">
    <div class="row form-group" ngModelGroup="weekday">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
        <label class="btn btn-info"
               *ngFor="let wday of wdays" 
               [class.active]="f.value.weekday[wday]">
          <input type="checkbox"
                 [name]="wday"
                 [id]="wday"
                 ngModel
                 [value]="wday">{{ wday }}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container>
    <div class="row form-group" *ngSwitchDefault>
      <p>Please choose something</p>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I have a radio button group that selects a value which is then set to `visitFrequency`, e.g. `weekday`. Now, whenever I choose this (same for other possible values) I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Monday' of undefined
```

Monday is the first value in the array `wdays` which is being looped through to create the checkboxes (if that was unclear).

I only receive this error, I don't receive the same error for `Tuesday`. This is consistent throughout. When I choose a difference `visitFrequency` I still receive the error but again only the first item of the array that is being looped through.

I suspect that the form values are not yet initiated and thus the error is thrown. The thing is that it doesn't happen when the component is being loaded.

Comment: Infomation is not enough for answering. First, you may miss place `ngSwitchDefault`. Second, your input tag must misuse `ngModel`. Last, you don't mention if the rest of array data display well or not.

Comment: What more information do you need? I don't have access to more than that either. Good catch on the `ngSwitchDefault`. What do you mean by the latter? Why must it misuse `ngModel`? I'm using the template-driven approach.

Comment: you don't bind any thing on `ngModel`

Comment: You don't need to bind anything to `ngModel`. It's not a misuse, it's standard practice if you don't plan on using the input in the component but only save the value to the form.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that approach before. It's not a common use case. By the way, the best way to reproduce the problem is to create a plunkr to show the problem, you can try my plunkr template https://plnkr.co/edit/bcxczZ2Tzyee70TtLrIJ

Comment: Here is a question that explains the case for `ngModel` without banana wrapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191427/does-ngmodel-create-two-way-data-binding-if-used-without-banana-wrapping

Comment: I am creating the `Plunkr` now, thanks for your template.

Comment: Here is the link to the `Plunkr`: https://plnkr.co/edit/MOQ1evhsAocw3cJrYM0q?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what's your problem now. It's your misuse about `ngModelGroup`. You use its value before its initiation.

see `[class.active]="f.value.weekday[wday]"`, if you remove this code from your plunkr, it works fine. Of course, it's not what you want.

#### #1

see my fork plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/CYkVFt4mb7sq98riviIZ?p=preview.
I create a `checkClass` to log down the value of form. Obviously, `ngModuleGroup` get its child controls' value until second round of change detection.

This is a poor way to avoid error, because the method will be called every change detection.

#### #2

There is another way, see this reference: this reference issue [Angular2 calling custom function after ngSwitch new view is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427670/angular2-calling-custom-function-after-ngswitch-new-view-is-created).

you can create a directive to detect the initiation of switch case. And then assign the initial value object like `{monday: '', tuesday: '' //...}` to `ngModelGroup`, then you may get no error with better performance.

#### #3

forget to mention one native support, <del>like `f.value?.weekday?[wday]`</del>.
[Angular haven't support the syntax like `arr?[x]` yet](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6798). A workaround should be `f.value?.weekday && f.value.weekday[wday]`

Comment: I'm still flabbergasted why this is happening. You are speaking about a misuse, would you not use `ngModelGroup` in that way? I saw the exact same implementation elsewhere.

Comment: I have add another approach. Your misuse is because you use it with `ngSwitch` which dynamically init and destroy view. That reflects the same in form data structure. If you have any problem. ping me.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Your #3 solution throws the following error for me though: `Conditional expression f.value?.weekday?[wday] requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [f.value?.weekday?[wday]]`

Comment: sorry, sound like [Angular doesn't support this syntax like `arr?[x]` yet](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6798) .

Comment: The solution 3 is perfect for the moment and I will look out for the changes to Angular syntax.

Comment: It may not. Because of Angular compilation for template, it just hides the #1 behind in the generated code.